# ffmpeg loosing quality video

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Everything is good but my quality result of the video is too low , its my first time using ffmpeg

This is my command

```
I/System.out: "-y" "-noautorotate" "-ss" "0" "-t" "31" "-i" "/storage/emulated/0/Download/20210227_175547.mp4" "-vf" "crop=w=3837:h=2160:x=1:y=-2070" "-r" "15" "-vcodec" "mpeg4" "-acodec" "copy" "-b:v" "2500k" "/storage/emulated/0/VEditor/VideoCroper/20210227_175547-0-13.mp4"
```

Comment: Add "-vb"  "20M" before your output path. This will give you better quality.

Comment: Why use old mpeg4 instead of a more modern encoder such as libx264, libx265, libvpx-vp9?

Comment: @llogan its my first time using ffmpeg . i will try to explore more and try that modeern encoder

Comment: @cropperteam Use `I/System.out: "-y" "-noautorotate" "-ss" "0" "-t" "31" "-i" "/storage/emulated/0/Download/20210227_175547.mp4" "-vf" "crop=w=3837:h=2160:x=1:y=-2070" "-r" "15" "-vcodec" "libx264" "-crf" "18" "-acodec" "copy" "/storage/emulated/0/VEditor/VideoCroper/20210227_175547-0-13.mp4"` and read [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). This assumes ffmpeg is configured with `--enable-libx264`.

Comment: @llogan still getting low quality this is my full command 
`"-y","-noautorotate", "-ss", Start, "-t", Duration, "-i",file_name, "-strict", "experimental", "-vf",sb.toString(), "-r", "15", "-ab", "128k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-acodec", "copy", "-b:v", "2500k", "-sample_fmt", "s16", "-ss", "0", "-t", this.Duration, Output}, Output);`

Comment: @cropperteam Why are you using mpeg4 instead of libx264? Why did you add `-strict experimental`? Replace `-b:v 2500k` with `-q:v 2` if you are stuck with mpeg4.

Comment: @llogan already changed to libx264 , and its works ,

Comment: @cropperteam The problem is solved now?

Comment: @llogan yes brother thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `libx264` instead of old `mpeg4`:

```
I/System.out: "-y" "-noautorotate" "-ss" "0" "-t" "31" "-i" "/storage/emulated/0/Download/20210227_175547.mp4" "-vf" "crop=w=3837:h=2160:x=1:y=-2070" "-r" "15" "-vcodec" "libx264" "-crf" "23" "-acodec" "copy" "-movflags +faststart" "/storage/emulated/0/VEditor/VideoCroper/20210227_175547-0-13.mp4"
```

Control quality with the `-crf` option. More info at [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).